# Delay between username and password during tty login

Tags: arch-linux, login, tty, lag, agetty

Recently, I noticed that when using tty to login to my computer, there was a delay (around 20 seconds) between the time I enter my username and the time I'm getting asked for my password. Where can it come from ?

I don't have such delay when using `su username` or `ssh username@localhost` and my password is asked right away.

I'm using Arch Linux with kernel 5.14.16.

**EDIT**

Finally found the problem. There was a broken module in PAM (fingerprint auth) which needed to timeout before asking a password. Just disabled the module.

Comment: Where's authentication coming from? Are you standalone or is there a remote server - RADIUS or Samba, for instance - that's authenticating your ID?

Comment: It's standalone authentication, there are no remote servers.

Comment: THANKS! This was a bug I couldn't fix for ages.